# Substituir caracteres especiais e letras maiusculas

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse código que copia tudo que se digita em um input para o outro, quero que quado ele copia para o outro input **substitua caracteres especiais, espaços com o "-" e letras minusculas**. Como poderia fazer como jquery?

```
$('.mirror').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.'+$(this).attr('class')).val($(this).val());
})


<input type="text" class="mirror" placeholder="one">
<input type="text" class="mirror" placeholder="two">
```

Exemplo de entrada: `Ação Esperada`

Saída esperada: `acao-esperada`

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o `str.replace` do JavaScript?

Comment: $('.mirror').on('keyup', function() {
    $str.replace(('.'+$(this).attr('class')).val($(this).val()));
    
});

Fiz assim e nao deu

Comment: Você quer substituir tais caracteres pelo quê? Esse seu `replace` não parece fazer sentido. Você já leu a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) da função?

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do texto que queres substituir e como deve ficar?

Comment: Ação Esperada

acao-esperada

Answer (score 2):

Usando Expressão regular  `/[^\w\s]/gi, '-'` para substituir caracteres especias por tracinho `(-)` e a seguir a função   `toLowerCase()`  para transformar em letras minusculas chegaremos ao resultado esperado.

> Nos arrays  `find`  e   `replace` pode configurar os caracteres a serem substituídos respectivamente.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.mirror').on('keyup', function() {
 
 var v1 = document.getElementById("codigo").value ;
    
 var find = ["ã","à","á","ä","â","è","é","ë","ê","ì","í","ï","î","ò","ó","ö","ô","ù","ú","ü","û","ñ","ç"]; "à","á","ä","â","è","é","ë","ê","ì","í","ï","î","ò","ó","ö","ô","ù","ú","ü","û","ñ","ç"
 var replace = ["a","a","a","a","a","e","e","e","e","i","i","i","i","o","o","o","o","u","u","u","u","n","c"];

    for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
        v1 = v1.replace(new RegExp(find[i], 'gi'), replace[i]);
    }

    var desired = v1.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
    desired = desired.toLowerCase();

    var v2 = document.getElementById("copia").value = desired;
    
});   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="codigo" class="mirror" placeholder="one">
<input type="text" id="copia" class="mirror" placeholder="two">
```

Comment: Se digitar "ação", o resultado esperado é "acao", como [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216614/substituir-caracteres-especiais-e-letras-maiusculas#comment442915_216614).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que entendi, você quer criar uma espécie de *slug* no segundo `input` a partir dos dados informados no primeiro. Para isso, utilize a função abaixo:

```js
function slugify(str) {
  
  // Converte o texto para caixa baixa:
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  
  // Remove qualquer caractere em branco do final do texto:
  str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

  // Lista de caracteres especiais que serão substituídos:
  const from = "ãàáäâẽèéëêìíïîõòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
  
  // Lista de caracteres que serão adicionados em relação aos anteriores:
  const to   = "aaaaaeeeeeiiiiooooouuuunc------";
  
  // Substitui todos os caracteres especiais:
  for (let i = 0, l = from.length; i < l; i++) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
  }

  // Remove qualquer caractere inválido que possa ter sobrado no texto:
  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '');
  
  // Substitui os espaços em branco por hífen:
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

  return str;
};

console.log(slugify("Ação Esperada"));
```

> Função baseada na apresentada nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5782563/1452488) no SOen.

Ou seja, utilizando com os `input`:

```js
function slugify(str) {
  
  // Converte o texto para caixa baixa:
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  
  // Remove qualquer caractere em branco do final do texto:
  str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

  // Lista de caracteres especiais que serão substituídos:
  const from = "ãàáäâẽèéëêìíïîõòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
  
  // Lista de caracteres que serão adicionados em relação aos anteriores:
  const to   = "aaaaaeeeeeiiiiooooouuuunc------";
  
  // Substitui todos os caracteres especiais:
  for (let i = 0, l = from.length; i < l; i++) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
  }

  // Remove qualquer caractere inválido que possa ter sobrado no texto:
  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '');
  
  // Substitui os espaços em branco por hífen:
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

  return str;
};

$(function () {

  $("#input-one").on("keyup", function (event) {
  
      $("#input-two").val(slugify($(this).val()));
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input-one" class="mirror" placeholder="one">
<input type="text" id="input-two" class="mirror" placeholder="two">
```

Perceba que eu defini o atributo `id` para cada campo e o utilizei para selecionar devidamente o campo que desejo obter ou alterar o valor.

Comment: Ele também quer substituir os caracteres especiais pelo tracinho ( - ). Agora te  pergunto ç é caracterer especial?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, não. Veja o comentário dele na pergunta. Adicionei o exemplo no corpo da pergunta para evitar confusão.

Comment: blz, agora vi o comentario, vou ter que trabalhar mais né :)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sobre o `ç`, acredito que sim, pois não consta na tabela ASCII. Não sei exatamente o objetivo de remover esses caracteres neste contexto, mas partindo do pressuposto que será utilizado em algum lugar que não possui suporte a esses caracteres, também não haveria suporte para o `ç`.

Comment: entendido, sua explicação tem tudo a ver, valeu

Answer (score 0):

Usa assim o substrig/replace:

```
$('.mirror').on('keyup', function() {
    var str = $(this).val();
    str = str.replace(".", "");
    str = str.replace(",", ""); //Tu adicionas todos os caracteres que tu queres remover.
    var res = str.replace("#", ""); //E no último, joga na variável 'res'
    $("#novoTexto").val(res);
})

<input type="text" class="mirror" placeholder="one">
<input id="novoTexto" type="text" placeholder="two">
```

Comment: ele não copia do outro lado com esse código

Comment: alterei a resposta pra ti @WagnerMartinsBodyboard

Comment: Mastiguei aí pra ti @WagnerMartinsBodyboard . Adicionei um "id" e retirei a classe "mirror" no "two".

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.mirror').on('keyup', function() {
    var str = $(this).val();
    var res = str.replace(" ", "-");
    $('.'+$(this).attr('class')).val(res).val();
})
```

Fiz assim agora ele muda nois dois inputs quero que mude apenas no **input id=two** como faria?

Comment: Mude o seletor no jQuery para o respectivo id.

Comment: pode me dizer como faço isso?

Comment: `$('#two.'+$(this).attr('class')).val(res);` Alternativamente, porque este evento roda num elemento cuja classe é `mirror`, só `$('#two.mirror').val(res);` já resolve...